# Can a class that tracks time be immutable?

Tags: oop, time, immutability

Let's say I have a simple class in Java that stores a time stamp:

```
public final class Timestamp {
  private final long value;

  public Timestamp(final long value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public long getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

That's immutable. But what if instead of `getValue()` I write a method called `getProgress()`?

```
public final class Timestamp {
  private final long value;

  public Timestamp(final long value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public float getProgress() {
    return (SomeExternalPlace.getTimestamp() - value) / SomeFloatConstant;
  }
}
```

The object's state never changes, but the value from `getProgress()` *does* change over time.

Is the latter class considered immutable? Why or why not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is immutable, because its state (the `value` field) cannot change once an instance of `Timestamp` has been created. The timestamp represents a certain point in time, and that cannot be changed.

Data returned from the methods doesn't necessarily need to be always the same.

Additionally, `Timestamp` exhibits all the properties you'd expect from an immutable object (e.g., thread-safety).

Here's another "weird" example of immutability:

```
class LazyList<T>
{
    private readonly T _head;
    private LazyList<T> _tail;
    private readonly Func<LazyList<T>> _tailDelegate;

    private bool _created;

    public LazyList(T head, Func<LazyList<T>> tailDelegate)
    {
        _head = head;
        _tailDelegate = tailDelegate;
        _created = false;
    }

    public T GetHead()
    {
        return _head;
    }

    public LazyList<T> GetTail()
    {
        if(! _created)
        {
            _tail = _tailDelegate();
            _created = true;
        }

        return _tail;
    }
}
```

As you can see, the `_tail` isn't *really* immutable - it's null when `LazyList<T>` is instantiated, and is assigned only when the client calls `GetTail()`. But that really doesn't matter. Once the tail is created, it doesn't change; and before that, the tail still "exists", it just hasn't been realized yet.

This is actually how Scala's immutable [`Stream`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.immutable.Stream)s are implemented.

Comment: "Data returned from the methods doesn't necessarily need to be always the same." -- I think that could be debated. It's fuzzy across languages, but a common definition in Java is that "[an immutable object's] state cannot be seen to change by callers." (Brian Goetz, Java Concurrency In Practice, and JSR305). In the example given in the question, the object appears to change even though its fields don't. In your example, the LazyList is not seen to change by callers, the lazy computation of the tail is just a performance optimisation. I would argue that the Timestamp class is not immutable.